# Repetitive(duplicate) Element Delete from an Int Array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to delete the repetitive(duplicate) element from an array. I am facing difficulties to do that. I have tried several ways. Can anybody find the solution for me please.

```
Input: 3,5,6,7,3,5,3,8
Expected Output: 3 5 6 7 8
```

My Code:

```
package com.nanofaroque.DeleteRepElementInArray;

public class DeleteElementRepetativeElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Here is the input Array...
        int[] arr = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 3, 8 };
        int end = arr.length;// finding the length of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < end; j++) {
                if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                    for (int k = j; k < end; k++) {
                        arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
                    }
                    end--;
                } else {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected Output: 3 5 6 7 8

Comment: so you want to delete from 3,5,3. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html).

delete from the ending

```
int[] arr = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 3, 8 };
int noOfItemsToBeDeleted=4;
for (int i = 0; i < noOfItemsToBeDeleted; i++) {
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        arr = ArrayUtils.remove(arr, arr.length-1);
    }
}
for (int i : arr) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

delete from the beginning

```
int[] arr = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 3, 8 };
int noOfItemsToBeDeleted=4;
for (int i = 0; i < noOfItemsToBeDeleted; i++) {
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        arr = ArrayUtils.remove(arr, 0);
    }
}
for (int i : arr) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

---

--EDIT--

as per your last comment you want to remove duplicate values only from an array. Try `Set<Integer>` to remove duplicate values.

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 8 };

Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : arr) {
    set.add(i);
}

// new array if you need it
int[] newArray = new int[set.size()];
int index = 0;
for (int i : set) {
    System.out.print(i+" ");
    newArray[index++] = i;
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 4 0
```

Comment: It will delete four of the element from the beginning or ending. It is not my expected out i am looking for .. Thanks for trying

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Can `ArrayUtils` help you in this issue?

Comment: ArrayUtils does not import to my Eclipse. I dont know why is that?

Comment: `commons-lang.jar` is needed.

Comment: Please have a look at last option.

Comment: Why did you used 3 and 6? Array size can be infinite. We never know that.

Comment: Can you use `ArrayList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`. That is best option in place of static `int[]`.

Comment: Did you understand my question? Let me explain ..Let say you have an array arr={1 2 3  5 6 7 8 9 5 4 7 8 9 3 2 1 0 3 4 8}; There are lot of element have their repeat. Now you have to delete repeatation. So outPut will be: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 4 0

Comment: oh that's the question. use `Set<Integer>`. Let me update it in my post.

Comment: I have updated it in my post. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated your question to make it more clear. I was confused in repetitive word.